# T-SQL Constraint on Foreign Key and one Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to set up a small database to organize permissions. I am using those four tables:

- `User`, columns: UserID, Name
- `UserGroup`, columns: UserGroupID, Name
- `UserGroupUsers`, columns: UserID, UserGroupID
- `Permission`, columns: PermissionID, UserID, UserType, Permission, PermissionValue

Rules:

- One User can be in multiple groups
- One Group can have multiple users
- A permission can be part of an user but also of an usergroup.

Now I am trying to set up a constraint, whenever I delete an `user` or a `userGroup`, I also want to delete the `Permission` rows with a database constraint.

The relation of `user` and `userGroup` are as following:

One row of `User` can have multiple rows in `Permissions` but with the extra condition: `UserType = 1`.

Sames for the groups:

One row of `UserGroup` can have multiple rows in `Permissions` but with the extra condition `UserType = 2`.

Examples:

Table: Permissions:

```
PermissionID   |   UserID   | UserType | Permission | PermissionValue
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1                  1          1          MainMenu      15
2                  1          2          MainMenu      2
```

Row 1 representing an user-Permission of the user with userID = 1

Row 2 representing an userGroup-permission of the usergroup with usergroupID = 1.

What I tried so far:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.permissions 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_permissionsAccounts 
  FOREIGN KEY(userID) 
  REFERENCES dbo.users(userID) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

but this one is actually wrong, since it should only happen to UserType=1

The next thing I tried, was adding a column `UserType` to both tables `Users` and `Groups`, including the type, but there I get the message:

> the field is not part of a key.

Source on this try:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.permissions 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_permissionsAccounts 
   FOREIGN KEY(userID, accountType)
   REFERENCES dbo.users(userID, accountType) 
       ON UPDATE CASCADE 
       ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I am using SQL Server 2008

I'd be happy with any suggestions. thanks in advance.

Edit for Solution:

i've edited the table:

`Permission`, columns: PermissionID, UserID, UserGroupID, Permission, PermissionValue.

i have set `null-allowed` attribute on both: `UserID` and `UserGroupID` but added a check constraint which only allows one of both fields to be filled, other has to be null:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.permissions
WITH CHECK ADD  
CONSTRAINT chk_permissions
CHECK  (
       ([AccountID] IS NULL AND [AccountGroupID] IS NOT NULL) OR 
       ([AccountID] IS NOT NULL AND [AccountGroupID] IS NULL)
        )
```

now i was able to add my default constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.permissions 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_permissionsUsers
  FOREIGN KEY(userID) 
  REFERENCES dbo.users(userID) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.permissions 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_permissionsUserGroups
  FOREIGN KEY(userGroupID) 
  REFERENCES dbo.usergroups(userGroupID) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: So if `UserType` is 2, is in fact `UserID` meant to contain a `UserGroupID` from the `UserGroup` table rather than an actual `UserID` from the `User` table? If not, I'm not sure I understand this structure

Comment: yes, correct. i will add an example to the question.

Comment: Then I'd strongly recommend the two column approach advocated by Rhys or a) Give it a name that clearly indicates it will be *either* a user or a group ID, or b) Give it a name that is strictly neutral on what type of ID it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the table design a little? If you add UserGroupId to the Permission table then this becomes much simpler. There is no need for the UserType column (unless you want it of course). Rows in the Permission table would have *either* a UserId *or* a UserGroupId, but not both (a check constraint can enforce this).

Also, as noted by @Damien_The_Unbeliever, using a column called UserId to hold either a UserId or a UserGroupId is not ideal. If you have to do this then change the name of the column to prevent confusion.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i will try to solve this via check constraint. but mainly the database table design was a team descision, in the first, (without the constraints) this was an easier understanding somehow. i will give feedback on monday. i really appreciate this. thanks.

Comment: i tried the it this way and it worked out. i have edited the question. thanks again.